React Native Maps : inaccurate marker location when updating dynamically the marker coordinates via socket io client
I am trying to update the marker coordinates using socket io client, there's no error shown, but the marker location in the map is not as accurate as expected.
Please check my code snippet shown below.
Mapview component:
<MapView
        style={styles.map}
        region={{
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        }}
>
    <UrlTile
          urlTemplate="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          maximumZ={19} 
    />

    <Marker
          coordinate={{ latitude: lat, longitude: lng }}
          title={"San Francisco"}
          description={"This is a description of the oten"}
    />
</MapView>

useEffect function:
const [lat, setLat] = useState(10.330121);
const [lng, setLng] = useState(123.900298);

useEffect(() => {
    const socketIo = io(SOCKET_URL);

    socketIo.on("testLocation", (data) => {
        console.log("testLocation", data);
        setLat(data.lat);
        setLng(data.lng);
    });

    // - disconnect on unmount
    return () => {
        socketIo.disconnect();
    };
}, []);


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

did u tried use map component outside of main func? may be when state has been changed , the map component must be re-rendered

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
